# Почему создается текстура без прорисовки цветов пикселей в DirectX11?

Tags: c++, imgui, directx-11

При помощи следующего участка кода я преобразую изображение из окна в текстуру и возвращаю Shader Resource View.

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* Graphics::GetFrame()

HRESULT hr = S_OK;

wrl::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> backBufferTex;
pSwap->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(backBufferTex.GetAddressOf()));

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
backBufferTex->GetDesc(&texDesc);

texDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> pSceneTex;
GFX_THROW_INFO(pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, NULL, &pSceneTex));

wrl::ComPtr<ID3D11RenderTargetView> backBufferRTV;
pContext->OMGetRenderTargets(1u, backBufferRTV.GetAddressOf(), pDSV.GetAddressOf());

wrl::ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> backBufferRTVResource;
backBufferRTV->GetResource(&backBufferRTVResource);

pContext->CopyResource(pSceneTex.Get(), backBufferRTVResource.Get());

D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc = {};
shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = texDesc.Format;
shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

GFX_THROW_INFO(pDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(pSceneTex.Get(), &shaderResourceViewDesc, &pResource));

//pContext->PSGetShaderResources(0u, 1u, pResource.GetAddressOf());

return pResource.Get();
```

Далее, я использую метод ImGui::Image для отрисовки текстуры:

```
ImGui::Begin("Observe");
auto TextureView = wnd.Gfx().GetFrame();
ImTextureID my_tex_id = TextureView;
ImGui::Image(my_tex_id, ImVec2(400, 300));
ImGui::End();
```

В результате я получаю
[image: Результат кода]

Предполагаю, что проблема с PixelShader, однако что конкретно не знаю.

```
PixelShader.hsls

cbuffer CBuf {
    float4 face_colors[8];
};

float4 main(uint tid: SV_PrimitiveID) : SV_Target{

     return face_colors[(tid/2)%8];
}
```

Передача константного буфера на цвета осуществляется через следующие действия

1.
if (!IsStaticInitialized()) {

```
    struct Vertex {
        dx::XMFLOAT3 pos;
    };
    auto model = Cube::Make<Vertex>();

    AddStaticBind(std::make_unique<VertexBuffer>(gfx, model.vertices));

    auto pvs = std::make_unique<VertexShader>(gfx, L"ColorIndexVS.cso");
    auto pvsbc = pvs->GetBytecode();
    AddStaticBind(std::move(pvs));

    AddStaticBind(std::make_unique<PixelShader>(gfx, L"ColorIndexPS.cso"));

    AddStaticIndexBuffer(std::make_unique<IndexBuffer>(gfx, model.indices));

    struct PixelShaderConstants
    {
        struct
        {
            float r;
            float g;
            float b;
            float a;
        } face_colors[8];
    };
    const PixelShaderConstants cb2 =
    {
        {
            { 1.0f,0.0f,1.0f },
            { 1.0f,0.0f,0.0f },
            { 0.0f,1.0f,0.0f },
            { 0.0f,0.0f,1.0f },
            { 1.0f,1.0f,0.0f },
            { 0.0f,1.0f,1.0f },
        }
    };

    AddStaticBind(std::make_unique<PixelConstantBuffer<PixelShaderConstants>>(gfx, cb2));

    const std::vector<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC> ied =
    {
        { "Position",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,0,0,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0 },
    };
    AddStaticBind(std::make_unique<InputLayout>(gfx, ied, pvsbc));

    AddStaticBind(std::make_unique<Topology>(gfx, D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST));
}
        else {
            SetIndexFromStatic();
        }
```

2. Передача буферов в шаблонный класс и работа с ними:

'''

```
template<typename C>
class ConstantBuffer : public Bindable
{
public:
    void Update(Graphics& gfx, const C& consts)
    {
        INFOMAN(gfx);

        D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE msr;
        GFX_THROW_INFO(GetContext(gfx)->Map(
            pConstantBuffer.Get(), 0u,
            D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0u,
            &msr
        ));
        memcpy(msr.pData, &consts, sizeof(consts));
        GetContext(gfx)->Unmap(pConstantBuffer.Get(), 0u);
    }
    ConstantBuffer(Graphics& gfx, const C& consts)
    {
        INFOMAN(gfx);

        D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbd;
        cbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
        cbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
        cbd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
        cbd.MiscFlags = 0u;
        cbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(consts);
        cbd.StructureByteStride = 0u;

        D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA csd = {};
        csd.pSysMem = &consts;
        GFX_THROW_INFO(GetDevice(gfx)->CreateBuffer(&cbd, &csd, &pConstantBuffer));
    }
    ConstantBuffer(Graphics& gfx)
    {
        INFOMAN(gfx);

        D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbd;
        cbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
        cbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
        cbd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
        cbd.MiscFlags = 0u;
        cbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(C);
        cbd.StructureByteStride = 0u;
        GFX_THROW_INFO(GetDevice(gfx)->CreateBuffer(&cbd, nullptr, &pConstantBuffer));
    }
protected:
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> pConstantBuffer;
};

template<typename C>
class VertexConstantBuffer : public ConstantBuffer<C>
{
    using ConstantBuffer<C>::pConstantBuffer;
    using Bindable::GetContext;
public:
    using ConstantBuffer<C>::ConstantBuffer;
    void Bind(Graphics& gfx) noexcept override
    {
        GetContext(gfx)->VSSetConstantBuffers(0u, 1u, pConstantBuffer.GetAddressOf());
    }
};

template<typename C>
class PixelConstantBuffer : public ConstantBuffer<C>
{
    using ConstantBuffer<C>::pConstantBuffer;
    using Bindable::GetContext;
public:
    using ConstantBuffer<C>::ConstantBuffer;
    void Bind(Graphics& gfx) noexcept override
    {
        GetContext(gfx)->PSSetConstantBuffers(0u, 1u, pConstantBuffer.GetAddressOf());
    }
};
```

'''

Comment: ¿А что там в face_colors лежит?

Comment: Отредактировал сообщение, и добавил работу с буферами цветов для шейдеров